# Text disappearing from asp Label control, but getting rendered

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, ascx

I have a label control where I modify the text server side before it gets rendered. The weird thing is, when I break at the line where I access the text value, the result is an empty string, but when the control is rendered to the page, the Text contents are there.

```
<asp:Label id="_tealiumScript" Runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
    abc
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var GetServerName = function() {
            var servername;
            try { servername = "<%=Server.MachineName %>"; } catch (e) { }
            return servername;
        }
    </script>
</asp:Label>
```

On top of that, when I take out the contents in the  element, I can access the text; I can see "abc" as well as the opening and closing script tags. All this, and it works in other controls in the same platform.

This is where I try to access the text in a class called TrackingUserControl (which the code from the codebehind above inherits from):

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = _tealiumScript != null ? _tealiumScript.Text : " not here either";


        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

***Edit:***

I tried taking different parts out, and what I found was when I have the text

```
"<%=Server.MachineName %>"
```

in there, I can't access the text property of the control. if I take it out, it's fine. If anyone can enlighten me on why this happens I will be more than grateful!

Comment: So what is the problem exactly, the text is not there when you debug, but renders to the page fine? Or am I misunderstanding what you wrote?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are putting the break point?

Comment: Updated, the example is a little contrived, but I was inspecting it in the OnLoad, OnPrerender, and Render events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried taking different parts out, and what I found was when I have the text

```
"<%=Server.MachineName %>"
```

in there, I can't access the text property of the control. if I take it out, it's fine.